# Limiting concurrent SFTP sessions in Go

Tags: go, ssh, sftp

I'm not really into Go, but trying to fix a bit of GO sourcecode, which is working fine in total, but the device which is being accessed is having issues with multiple SSH/SFTP, fast after each other or at the same time, which causes a reboot of the device sometimes

I would like to make sure, only 1 SSH session is started and active at the time.

Anyone has the smoking gun for me ?

Cheers on advance!

```
func (c *SftpClient) Download() ([]byte, error) {
        ch := make(chan *downloadResult)

        timeout := time.After(c.retryTimeout)
        started := false

        go func() {
                data := []byte{}
                resultErr := error(nil)

                defer func() {
                        ch <- &downloadResult{
                                data: data,
                                err:  resultErr,
                        }
                }()

                for {
                        select {
                        case <-timeout:
                                if util.DebugLogging() {
                                        log.Info("Timed-out on file downloading from SFTP server")
                                }

                                data = []byte{}
                                resultErr = fmt.Errorf("SFTP client timed-out")
                                return
                        default:
                        }

                        if started {
                                time.Sleep(c.retryWaitInterval)
                        }

                        started = true
                        downloadedData, downloaded := c.tryDownload()
                        if !downloaded {
                                continue
                        }

                        data = downloadedData
                        break
                }
        }()

        result := <-ch
        return result.data, result.err
}
```

```
func (c *SftpClient) tryDownload() ([]byte, bool) {
        defer func() {
                if err := recover(); err != nil {
                        log.Errorf("panic occurred: %s", err)
                }
        }()

        client, err := sshDial(c.serverAddr, c.retryTimeout, c.sshConfig)
        data := []byte{}
        downloaded := false

        if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Failed to SSH dial to %s: %s", c.serverAddr, err)
                return data, downloaded
        }
        defer client.Close()

        
        // open an SFTP session over an existing ssh connection.
        sftpClient, err := sftp.NewClient(client)
        if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Failed to connect via SFTP to %s: %s", c.serverAddr, err)
                return data, downloaded
        }
        defer sftpClient.Close()

        fList, err := sftpClient.ReadDir(c.directory)
        if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("Failed to read directory %s on %s: %s", c.directory, c.serverAddr, err)
                return data, downloaded
        }

        for _, item := range fList {
                if !item.IsDir() && strings.HasPrefix(item.Name(), c.filename) {
                        fp := filePath.Join(c.directory, item.Name())

                        remoteFile, err := sftpClient.Open(fp)
                        if err != nil {
                                log.Errorf("Failed to open remote file %s on %s: %s", fp, c.serverAddr, err)
                                continue
                        }

                        wt := c.newFileWriter(item.Name())

                        n, err := remoteFile.WriteTo(wt)
                        if err != nil || n == 0 {
                                log.Errorf("Failed to read remote file %s on %s: %s", fp, c.serverAddr, err)
                                break
                        }

                        // remove the remote file
                        if c.removeAfterDownload {
```

```
func sshDial(addr string, retryTimeout time.Duration, sshConfig *ssh.ClientConfig) (*ssh.Client, error) {
        ch := make(chan *ssh.Client)

        go func() {
                client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", addr, sshConfig)
                if err != nil {
                        ch <- nil
                } else {
                        ch <- client
                }
        }()

        timeout := time.After(retryTimeout)

        select {
        case <-timeout:
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("SSH dialing timed-out")
        case client := <-ch:
                if client != nil {
                        return client, nil
                } else {
                        return nil, fmt.Errorf("SSH dialing timed-out")
                }
        }
}
```

I tried to build in sleeps, but this is not giving the result what i need.

Comment: sshDial is too complicated: `ssh.ClientConfig` has a `Timeout` field that you can use. No need for the internal channel, select, etc.

Comment: In general, the flow control in the examples is going to be hard to maintain. Most of this doesn't need channels or nested for-loops to do what you want. Making that as simple as possible will make it easier for you to control how many sessions exist and where. Also, we only see `sshDial()` - not what eventually calls it. Have you determined where extra sessions are being started from?

Comment: If you want to be more graceful to the devices you're connecting to, return `error` up the stack when they occur instead of implementing your own retry loops. Then at the top of the stack, use something like this library for exponential backoff: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v4

Comment: @coxley the sshdial is called from tryDownload function, is a complicated package with task engines and so on, the program is working correctly if the devices does not has issues with non-thread safe sftp sessions (according to the vendor) - so trying to fix this at the end

Comment: `tryDownload` can only create one connection at a time, so there is no concurrency to limit. I'll second the comment about the code quality issues, this will repeatedly retry even in the face of unrecoverable errors, with no error checking or backoff at all. If there's a failure which makes sense to retry from, do so but with some sort of delay.